# Open problems from antiquity solved with analytic geometry

Tags: ho.history-overview, euclidean-geometry

E. T. Bell wrote in Men of Mathematics:

*Though the idea behind it all is childishly simple, yet the method of analytic geometry is so powerful that very ordinary boys of seventeen can use it to prove
results which would have baffled the greatest of the Greek geometers --
Euclid, Archimedes, and Apollonius.*

I don't necessarily believe everything in the book, but this passage sounds plausible enough to make me wonder.

Are there any good examples of an open problem from antiquity which seemed inaccessible, but was later easily solved by converting it to the Cartesian plane?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by easily but for instance, the impossibility of trisecting an angle or squaring a circle should qualify.

Comment: @Asvin I think those impossibility proofs involved a lot more than just analytic geometry. Like, Field Theory, and transcendence of $\pi$.

Comment: @Asvin I wish to specifically disqualify those examples. No Galois theory. No calculus, for that matter.

Comment: How do you *precisely* know that a problem "seemed inaccessible" to the old geometers?

Comment: Unless we are talking about some *very famous* unsolved problems (e.g. trisection of the angle, duplication of the cube, squaring of the circle) the fact of "being inaccessible" is matter of speculation.

Comment: For instance: Morley's theorem was not discovered by the Greeks. However, besides quick analytical proofs, there are also "classical" ones. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morley%27s_trisector_theorem

Comment: I think a less speculative version of this questions would be: Are there elementary geometric statements whose proof with analytic geometry is much easier to find than without it.

Comment: @LennartMeier, how about: given five points and a line, where does the line intersect the conic going through the five points?

Comment: Archimedes knew how to trisect an angle using a "neusis construction" with a *marked* ruler. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection#With_a_marked_ruler. The ancient Greeks didn't entirely ignore practical solutions to problems!

Comment: You are asking for a problem that *did* "baffle the greatest of the Greek geometers", whereas the text you quote only claims the existence of problems that, perhaps by design, fall easily to analytic geometry and which *would have* baffled them, had they been posed that problem and tried to solve it with Euclid's toolbox. I guess the main thing is for this hypothetical time-traveller to avoid posing it in such a way that the mere problem statement gives them the clues they need to invent elementary algebra and Cartesian geometry.

Comment: Basically, I wonder if the quotation is only trying to say, "the ancient Greeks would have struggled to operate a laptop to write the few lines of code necessary to factor a given product of two 10-digit primes". Well, yeah, unless they learned how, which they had no means to do on account of being ancient Greeks. But the claim is not that they *tried and failed* to do it, merely that they didn't have the tools to do it *if asked*. Which they weren't. (And, where the analogy breaks down, a laptop is not "childishly simple").

Comment: A side note: it's a bit of a stretch to call the proof of impossibility of trisecting an angle (like 60 degrees) "Galois theory". All you really need is that for two extension fields $E \subseteq F \subseteq K$, the degree $\dim_E F$ divides $\dim_E K$.

Answer (score 19):

A classic problem in this category is Alhazen's billiard problem. I reproduce a quote from  [100 Great Problems of Elementary Mathematics](https://books.google.nl/books?id=C5iH2dczNG4C&q=alhazen#v=onepage&q&f=false). The problem could not be solved using compass and ruler because its solution requires taking a cube root (see references at [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlhazensBilliardProblem.html)).

[image]

Comment: So there is Galois theory involved on the solution, against the OP's requirements

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi --- the solution given by Jack Elkin in [Mathematics Teacher](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27968003?read-now=1&refreqid=excelsior%3A8cb5801fbb173016cf10b709187ae9df&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) seems to require only elementary algebra.

Comment: Archimedes could have computed this to any desired accuracy. Pappus would have said: we see how to construct this by neusis, but not by plane methods like straightedge and compass. If Bell's comment suggests there are examples where the Greeks would have understood an answer, but were baffled in being unable to find it -- then this example does not support that claim.

Answer (score 15):

[This paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2691183?read-now=1&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) contains a very readable account of Descartes invention of analytic geometry and describes some questions that it can solve reasonably easily compared to methods familiar to the ancient greeks.

Even defining [conics sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section) in the plane is quite clumsy using the [directrix, focus and eccentricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Eccentricity,_focus_and_directrix). The [analytic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Standard_forms_in_Cartesian_coordinates) of a second degree equation is easier to remember and clearly superior when computing actual points of intersection for example.

[Descartes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem) is one that is tough to prove or perhaps even discover without analytic geometry. Descartes himself used this as an example of the power of his method in his correspondence with [Princess Elizabeth of Bohemia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elisabeth_of_the_Palatinate):

*Bos, Erik-Jan*, [**Princess Elizabeth of Bohemia and Descartes’ letters (1650-1665)**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.hm.2009.11.004), Hist. Math. 37, No. 3, 485-502 (2010). [ZBL1200.01012](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1200.01012).

Comment: So, you are answering a different version of the question? I mean, not the one with "being inaccessible", since Apollonius already knew a lot of things about conic sections.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi I interpreted "seemed inaccessible" to mean very difficult or even impossible if approached using classical greek mathematics. I agree that he greeks knew a huge amount about the properties of conic sections but they didn't have a systematic way to approach basic questions such as intersection or tangency.

Comment: I understand your interpretation, but the question has the tag "History of Maths". And, from the historical point of view, "seemed inaccessible" has a precise meaning: the perception of inaccessibility must be *documented*. Otherwise, as I said before, this is speculation.

Comment: We can *really* say that Descartes' Theorem would have "baffled" Apollonius? I cannot say this for sure, after all the Greeks were able to prove related statements like Pappus' theorem. What if Apollonius would have thought enough about Descartes' theorem? Nobody can know.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi I understand you make a very fair point, it's just that for this type of question I think it's worth allowing a looser interpretation and therefore a broader set of  possible answers. I wouldn't say that Pappus' theorem is particularly related to Descartes' Theorem. Pappus' theorem is about points on lines and collinearity so very classical in nature. It is a fundamental proposition that is almost axiomatic, being equivalent to commutativity of multiplication.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi  Descartes' theorem, on the other hand,  is about tangency of circles and the algebraic relations between their radii or curvature. This is a very different type of theorem with no obvious antecedent in Greek Mathematics I think.

Comment: oh, sorry, you were referring to Descartes' theorem about mutually tangent circles. I did not open your link and, since you were talking about conics, for some reason I misinterpreted "Descartes" for "Pascal" :-) Pascal's theorem about exagons inscribed in conics is  a natural generalization of Pappus' theorem, apparently unknown to classical geometers.

Answer (score 8):

I read this excerpt of *Men of Mathematics* as a private joke.
The very ordinary boy is Gauss of course. The number seventeen is a reference to the [heptadecagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptadecagon) that Gauss constructed at age nineteen.
This is the first progress since the Greeks concerning compass and straight-edge construction of regular polygons. It makes use of cartesian geometry, arithmetics, trigonometry and requires the solving of a degree seventeenth polynomial equation. Here is the solution from the Disquisitiones Arithmeticae.

\begin{align} 16\,\cos\frac{2\pi}{17} = & -1+\sqrt{17}+\sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}}+ \\
                                                     & 2\sqrt{17+3\sqrt{17}-
                                                        \sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}}-
                                                       2\sqrt{34+2\sqrt{17}}}\\
= & -1+\sqrt{17}+\sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}}+ \\
                                                     & 2\sqrt{17+3\sqrt{17}-
                                                        \sqrt{170+38\sqrt{17}}}.
 \end{align}

This would certainly have baffled the Greek. I understand *childish* in Bell's excerpt as refering to Gauss as a child prodigy.

Another mathematician commonly endowed with supernatural powers as a child is Pascal, who supposedly rediscovered all the Euclid axioms at age eleven (debunked by his sister).
His treaty *Essai sur les coniques* written at age sixteen contains his 
famous [hexagrammum mysticum theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_theorem), which generalises a previous result by Pappus. This a result that would have certainly baffled the Greeks. 
Pascal used projective geometry to reduce the proof to the case of a circle. Nowadays there are many short elegant proofs of Pascal theorem using analytic geometry.

Comment: The polynomial equation in question is of degree 16 (given by the 17th cyclotomic polynomial).

Comment: @Krause Indeed, thanks. I was thinking to the equation $X^{17}-1 = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Provocative answer (but not too much): checking the Fifth Postulate is a triviality in the Cartesian plane.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. The cartesian plane is a model for the complete set of euclidean postulates, so naturally you can not use it to decide whether or not one of the postulates is independent of the others. (I am sure you are aware of this yourself, but that doesn't change anything.)

Comment: Thank you for explaining me the meaning of ''provocative'' :-)

Comment: Joking apart, this answer wants to point out that the question is somehow ill-posed (see also my comments above).

Comment: As mathematicians, I feel we should not force our own standards of rigour upon others (mathematicians or otherwise). A differential equation can be ill-posed, a question can not be. The question has already received one answer that seems sensible to me; for me that is enough to conclude that the question has merit.

Comment: "A differential equation can be ill-posed, a question can not be"
So there exist no speculative questions? Interesting point of view.

Comment: To call a question "ill-posed" is to require the asker of the question to be just as precise as someone who asks for the solution to an ODE. However, not all questions can be asked with that kind (or level) of precision. (There is nothing interesting about this point of view, it's just a bad habit many mathematicians have: if they do not like a question, they start looking for loopholes and unintentional ambiguities.)

Comment: I simply require the asker of the question to adopt the standard of precision *required by the MO community*. And, in my opinion, saying that a problem from the antiquity "seemed inaccessible" is merely speculative, unless there are strong evidences of the contrary (like the famous three classical problems).

Comment: You are not convincing me that you are not being overly critical here. The OP is quoting E.T. Bell as the direct inspiration for this question. At the very minimum, this question can be meaningfully construed as "Are there any examples to back up Bell's claim, or is this an unwarranted exaggeration?"

Comment: I do not want to convince anyone. For me, it is pretty clear that saying something like "... to prove results which would have baffled the greatest of the Greek geometers" is mere speculation, and not appropriate for a MO question. There are four *documented* open problems from the classical era: the squaring of the circle, the duplication of the cube, the trisection of the angle and the independence of the 5th postulate from the others. Maybe the construction of the regular eptagon is a fifth one.  The rest is speculation.

Comment: How would this answer an unsolved question? The Greeks wanted to prove that the parallel postulate followed from the others, and this does not help with that.

Comment: *I know* this. Otherwise, I would not have written "provocative" answer.

Comment: The point of the answer is that analytic geometry is not only "powerful", but rather "intrinsecally stronger" than standard syntetic geometry. So the question is in some sense ill-posed (and there are also other problems with it, see my comments above).

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi, I thought that a provocative answer was a type of answer; thanks for clarifying that you meant something different.

Comment: A provocative answer (in this case) is an answer saying "Look, I think there are some problems with this question". After all, is it not true that the "proof" of the Fifth Postulate "baffled the best of the greek geometers"? And is it not true that it can be trivially carried out in the Cartesian model of the plane?

Answer (score 2):

I come across what looks like a good fit in Brianchon, *Solution de plusieurs problèmes de géométrie*, J. École Polytechnique **4**, nº 10 (1810) 1–15, [page 5](//gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k433667x/f6):

> *Pappus* reports also that the Greek geometers had tried in vain to solve this more general problem.
>
> « Given a circle and three poles, arranged in arbitrary manner, inscribe in this circle a triangle whose sides, extended if necessary, each go through one of the given poles. »
>
> With the help of analysis applied to geometry, the moderns easily overcame the difficulty, and this once famous question now amounts to very little; *Lagrange* has given a beautiful analytic solution (Mémoire de Berlin, [1776](//archive.org/details/uvresdelagrange04lagr/page/335))

(etc.; according to Senapati ([2019](//zbmath.org/?q=an:1415.51028)) Pappus had solved the case where the 3 points are aligned, in *Mathematicae collectiones*, Book 7, Prop. [117](//www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/2649666).)